# Browse hottest questions of previous months or previous weeks

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hot-questions

I love the "week" and "month" hottest questions tabs, they're useful to see hot stuff you missed.

I would love to browse the hottest questions of previous weeks and previous months for sites that I rarely visit. What do you think? Can it be done with some magic search query?