# Is there a database of old hot questions listed on stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Browse hottest questions of previous months or previous weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110693/browse-hottest-questions-of-previous-months-or-previous-weeks)

I very much enjoy reading the top 20 hottest questions from [the continuously compiled list kept here](https://stackexchange.com/questions). Perhaps a little too much, as I'm getting very sad whenever I don't log in for a few days , read all the current hot questions, and realize there was an entire half-week of hotness that I may never see. Is there any way to access hot questions lists from the past? Even a list of questions that passed a specific hotness at any point would be fine; I'm just looking for a way to satisfy my SE addiction... :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might benefit from subscribing to [The Stack Exchange Weekly Newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters)!

They contain a choice selection of Hot questions from the past week, some greatest hits, and even a few unanswered questions that might be worth a look.

Of course, you *do* have to pick a site. I wonder if a network-wide newsletter would interest anyone...

Comment: If it were network-wide, the questions would have to be really really hot. But it could be a way of discovering new sites.